# Create a sequence of indexes by block

Tags: r

I have a vector of length 4900. Only half of the vector stores relevant values.

The indexes at which the values are relevant are 51, ..., 100, 151, ..., 200,...

I skip 50 values, keep 50 and so on.

I want to extract those values and to store them in a new vector of length 2450.

I was thinking about doing:

```
new.vect <- old.vect[indexes]
```

Where indexes is the vector of indexes where relevant data is stored.

I was thinking about using the seq function, but can't create such a vector of indexes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use a logical vector to recycle and get the values from the vector

```
indexes <-  rep(c(FALSE, TRUE), each = 50)   
new.vect <- old.vect[indexes]
length(new.vect)
#[1] 2450
```

#### data

```
old.vect <- 1:4900
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, you can put the vector into a matrix with 50 rows and choose every other column:

```
vals <- c(matrix(1:4900, 50)[, c(FALSE, TRUE)])
length(vals)
[1] 2450
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a job for sliding window for which you can use `rollapply` function from `zoo` package which is designed for that purpose. So, you could alternatively do:

```
library(zoo)
m <- rollapply(51:4900, width=50, by=100, FUN=c)
inds <- c(t(m))

#> length(inds)
#[1] 2450
```